# Define $x\ln(x^2+3y^2)$ to be continuous

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> Can $x\ln(x^2+3y^2)$ be defined to be continuous at $(0,0)$? if so how?

So I have looked at the limit $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}x\ln(x^2+3y^2)$$ which is in the form of "$0\cdot -\infty$"

1. Can L'Hôpital theorem  be applied if we bring it to the form of $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\ln(x^2+3y^2)}{\frac{1}{x}}$$

   Which is in the form of $\frac{-\infty}{\infty}$ or it must be $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$?
2. How can we use L'Hôpital theorem in the case of multivariable limit?

Comment: You can't use (the usual) L'Hôpital's rule with multiple variables. Instead recall that for all positive numbers $x$, it holds that $\log(x)<x$.

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to0}\lim_{y\to0}x\ln(x^2+3y^2)=\lim_{x\to0}x\ln(x^2)=0$$

$$\lim_{y\to0}\lim_{x\to0}x\ln(x^2+3y^2)=\lim_{y\to0}0=0$$

Comment: @SimpleArt See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit#Counterexamples).

Comment: @GitGud Thank you for that.

Comment: @GitGud so $lim |x\ln(x^2+3y^2)|\leq lim|x(x^2+3y^2|\leq 0$ is sufficient?

Comment: @gbox My point exactly. Of course you can only use that fact if you know that $\lim |g|=0\implies \lim g=0$, but this is easy to prove.

Comment: @GitGud  $lim|(g)|=0 \rightarrow 0<lim(g)<0\rightarrow lim (g)=0$?

Comment: @gbox Hm? No. \lim (|g|)=0\implies \lim(g)=0. That's the fact you're implicitly using above. Let $f(x,y)=x\ln(x^2+3y^2)$, for all $x,y$ where at least one of them isn't zero. The proof goes like this: $\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}(|f(x,y)|)\leq\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left(\left|x(x^2+3y^2)\right|\right)=0$, therefore $\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}(|f(x,y)|)=0$. To conclude you need to use the fact stated at the beginning of this comment.

Comment: @gbox Don't hesitate to ask if you have any more questions.

Comment: @GitGud all is clear just for the $"lim|g|=0\rightarrow lim(g)=0"$.
I understand that this fact must be used, so we can solve it as you said.
but when you said that it "easy to prove" it is in this case? as $ln(x)>0$?

Comment: No, I meant it in general. For any function $g$, if the limit of $|g|$ is zero, then so is the limit of $g$.

Answer (score 1):

Define $x^2+3y^2=r^2$ with $r>0$, and $x=r \cos t$, $y=\frac{r}{\sqrt{3}} \sin (t)$. Then we can shrink the ellipse and approach $(0,0)$:

$$=\lim_{r \to 0^+} r \cos t \ln (r^2)=\lim_{r \to 0^+} 2\cos t \frac{\ln r}{\frac{1}{r}}$$

For all $t$.

Now standard l'Hopitals applies.

$$=\lim_{r \to 0^+} 2\cos t \frac{\frac{1}{r}}{\frac{-1}{r^2}}=\lim_{r \to 0^+} -2 r\cos t =0$$

By squeeze  theorem as $-2r \leq -2r\cos t \leq 2r$.